# Delivering Word documents with template

Tags: ms-word

My work routinely requires us to deliver documentation to our customer and other parts of the business. These documents are in the Microsoft Word format, and use a template stored on our servers. Our colleagues and the customer occasionally comment that the documents take a long time to open, as each one tries to connect to our server to locate the template, and either succeeds or fails and times out.

Is it possible to keep each document in their current format (i.e. with the template applied), but not require it to go looking for the template every time it is opened? Mostly for the customer who cannot access our servers for the template. Ideally, we do not want to deliver the template with the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to stop the document looking for the template. This is a bigger problem with some versions of Word than with others. But best would be to use a tool to link the document to Normal.dotm (or Normal.dot if this is pre-2007) before sending it out. The tool could generate a Document Variable to store the path to the original template so that another tool (or the same one) can re-attach the template when/if the document comes back.